# R: How to construct an index which states for each country pair the correlation between the yes votes?

Tags: r

I have a dataset which states for each UN resolution the country and the vote:

ResolutionID: 1,2,3,...
Country: US, CA, MX, ...
vote: yes, no, abstain
[Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qfavs.png)

I want to create an variable calculating for each country pair (e.g. US-CA, US-MX, MX-CA,...) the correlation of their voting records. Thus, providing an index for each country pairs friendship or strategic alliance.

What R Code do I have to used?

Citeation of the dataset: Erik Voeten "Data and Analyses of Voting in the UN General Assembly" Routledge Handbook of International Organization, edited by Bob Reinalda (published May 27, 2013)

What R Code do I have to used?

Comment: Package recommendation requests are off-topic. You might be able to rescue this question from closure by explaining in detail what you mean be "correlation". The answer might be a simple mathematical function that could be calcualted by separately applyuing that function to each pair of countries. You probably should first doa search since calculating pairwise values in datasets is likely to ahve been asked and answered already.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the algorithm for calculating the 'index of agreement' as proposed by Lijphart (1963), the below might be what you're after.

```
## set up sample data
set.seed(32446)
test = data.frame(rcid = rep(seq(3), each=10), country = rep(letters[seq(10)], 3), vote = sample(c("yes","no"),30, replace = T))
test$vote[sample(seq(30),3)] = "abstain" # add in a few abstentions
test = test[-sample(seq(30), 2), ] # remove some as missing
test


## set up the comparison df
allCountries = unique(test$country)

compdf = outer(allCountries, allCountries, paste)
compdf = data.frame(compdf[which(lower.tri(compdf))])
names(compdf) = "comp"

## cycle through the resolutions - use scoring as per Lijphart (1963): agreement by averaging the scores of 1 if there is agreement, 0 if the vote is opposite, and 0.5 if only one country abstains.
for(r in unique(test$rcid)){
  tempVotes = data.frame(countries = allCountries,
                         test$vote[which(test$rcid==r)][match(allCountries, test$country[which(test$rcid==r)])])
  tempVotes = outer(tempVotes[,2], tempVotes[,2], 
                    FUN=function(x,y){
                      ifelse(is.na(x) | is.na(y), NA, #NA if one country didn't vote
                             ifelse(x==y,1, ## 1 if they agree
                                    ifelse(x=="abstain" | y=="abstain", 0.5, # 0.5 if one side abstains
                                    0)
                                    ) # zero otherwise
                             )
                      } 
                    )
  compdf = cbind(compdf, tempVotes[which(lower.tri(tempVotes) )] )  
  names(compdf)[ncol(compdf)] = paste0("resolution_",r)
}

## calculate the mean score across resolutions
result = data.frame(comp = compdf$comp,
                    result = rowMeans(compdf[,seq(2, ncol(compdf)) ], na.rm=T)
                    )
result$result = 1-result$result # make it into a distance score, rather than agreement score

## create distance matrix and plot Dendrogram
library(ggplot2)
library(ggdendro)
distance = matrix(NA, length(allCountries), length(allCountries))
distance[which(lower.tri(distance))] = result$result
rownames(distance) = allCountries; colnames(distance) = allCountries
distance
cluster =  hclust(as.dist(distance))
ggdendrogram(cluster, rotate = FALSE, size = 2)
```

Lijphart, A. The Analysis of Bloc Voting in the General Assembly: A Critique and a Proposal. The American Political Science Review Vol. 57, No. 4 (Dec., 1963), pp. 902-917 https://www.jstor.org/stable/1952608